# Do I need seperate library with native function in order to load library with main function?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, sdl-2

Just like in topic do I need seperate lib with native fuction in order to load lib with main function in it ? Or is it recomennded to do so ?

At this moment I got those native functions compiled withing main.so but I am not sure if that's how it should be done.

native is lib loaded before main one

```
protected String[] getLibraries() {
        return new String[] {
            "SDL2",
            "hidapi",
            "native",
            "main"
        };
    }
```

And inside I got bunch of those native fucntion one of those is that one as example

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeRunMain(jstring library, jstring function, jobject array)
{
  return Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeRunMain("libmain.so", "SDL_main", NULL);
}
```

So far app is running loading libriaries and nothing more did tried to see if log_android is comming from main function but it does not.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by _"main function"_. The function that will be called by the VM after loading a native library is `JNI_OnLoad`.

Comment: On the face of it, you have an infinite recursion in this nativeRunMain native method. What were you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Michael I meant int main() one, I did read somewhere that JNI_OnLoad is not necesery, also logcat did say nothing about not found JNI_OnLoad

Comment: @AlexCohn do not mind what is inside this function. I want to run libmain.so but as soon it gets loaded it staight finish and app is closed. https://pastebin.com/X8AAtuaS

Comment: I am not sure I understand where the log lines you pasted come from. Can you show the relevant source code?

Comment: @AlexCohn I found solution and will post it in new post. And will answer your question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the solution to my issue was kinda weird. I had to generate whole package from scratch using one of build-scripts provided by SDL2. Then I copied some files from the old one and woila it now have access to int main() function.

Here is log from Logcat.

```
05-11 12:42:28.829 10315 10315 V SDL     : Device: santoni
05-11 12:42:28.829 10315 10315 V SDL     : Model: Redmi 4X
05-11 12:42:28.829 10315 10315 V SDL     : onCreate()
05-11 12:42:28.890 10315 10315 V SDL     : nativeSetupJNI()
05-11 12:42:28.890 10315 10315 V SDL     : AUDIO nativeSetupJNI()
05-11 12:42:28.890 10315 10315 V SDL     : CONTROLLER nativeSetupJNI()
05-11 12:42:28.900 10315 10315 D hidapi  : Initializing Bluetooth
05-11 12:42:28.929 10315 10315 D AccessibilityManager: current package=org.libsdl.app, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
05-11 12:42:28.952 10315 10315 V SDL     : onResume()
05-11 12:42:28.986 10315 10336 I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : dd15ef5, Ic280a69317
05-11 12:42:28.986 10315 10336 I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 05/09/17
05-11 12:42:28.986 10315 10336 I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
05-11 12:42:28.986 10315 10336 I Adreno  : Local Branch                     : 
05-11 12:42:28.986 10315 10336 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r5-rel
05-11 12:42:28.986 10315 10336 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : NONE
05-11 12:42:28.986 10315 10336 I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
05-11 12:42:28.994 10315 10336 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-11 12:42:28.994 10315 10336 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-11 12:42:28.995 10315 10315 V SDL     : surfaceCreated()
05-11 12:42:28.995 10315 10315 V SDL     : surfaceChanged()
05-11 12:42:28.995 10315 10315 V SDL     : pixel format RGB_565
05-11 12:42:28.996 10315 10315 V SDL     : Window size: 720x1230
05-11 12:42:28.996 10315 10315 V SDL     : Device size: 720x1280
05-11 12:42:29.001 10315 10315 V SDL     : nativeResume()
05-11 12:42:29.002 10315 10338 V SDL     : Running main function SDL_main from library /data/app/org.libsdl.app-1/lib/arm64/libmain.so
05-11 12:42:29.002 10315 10338 V SDL     : nativeRunMain()
```

Also off to next issue that awaits for me.